# How to upgrade libssl0.9.8 to install php5-fpm

Tags: php, libssl

I need to setup php on server where ROR and nginx are already configured .

When I am installing php5-fpm then there are one package libssl0.9.8 version dependency.

I have searched a lot and tried to remove and re-install package libssl0.9.8 but version is not updating .

I am getting below error when I am trying to install php5-fpm .

```
root@boxyroom:~#  sudo apt-get install php5-fpm -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-fpm: Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1) but 0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.13 is to be installed
            PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2) but 1.15.5.6ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Please let me know if any one has an idea to install the php5-fpm or upgrading package libssl0.9.8.

Thanks in advance .